# WPF Multiline TextBox Caret Position

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I have a multiline `TextBox` that that fills the space of it's containing window (both vertically and horizontally). When I give it focus to begin typing, the caret position is in the very center of the `TextBox`... which seems odd to me.

[image]

How can I have this start at the top?

The only thing I've found says to set `VerticalAlignment="Top"` but this has the undesirable effect of the `TextBox` no longer filling the height of its parent.

Here's the code, container is a standard Grid.

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True"
    Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="5 5 5 0" />
```

Comment: This is very weird. I've just tried to recreate this and it works for me from the get go (at the top).

Comment: When I try your sample code in an empty project, it places the caret at the top. Is there something else going on?

Comment: I don't have such effect, could you post screenshot and code what *may* affect textbox (to example, that `Desription` thing).

Comment: Are both VerticalAlignment AND VerticalContentAlignment set to top?

Comment: Must be something else effecting it, the Description is just a string. Hold on, I'll update with more code..

Comment: Nope just missing a setting. Strange no on else could reproduce.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two properties that you can set to fix your problem:

[`TextBox.TextAlignment` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.textalignment(v=vs.110).aspx)
[`Control.VerticalContentAlignment` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.verticalcontentalignment(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" 
    Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="5 5 5 0" 
    TextAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top" />
```

Comment: VerticalContentAlignment is what I was looking for. Thank you, sir.

Comment: This is odd; `VerticalContentAlignment` should be set to `Top` by default.  @aw04, are you using a custom style on your `TextBox`?  You should not need to set that value explicitly.

Comment: @MikeStrobel I was wondering why no one else could reproduce this, I'll have to see if something is applied globally (it's a large project) but personally... no I've only done what you see

Comment: +1 @MikeStrobel, I thought about mentioning that, but I figured that the question author must be working on a large project and unaware of the default `Style`s set up in it.